# print llvm target assembly

Tags: llvm

I am trying to print the assembly from a Sparc Target. I already can generate the IR from it however, somehow this doesn't work for the Target. I am not sure what to add since the llvm-is tool uses the ParseIRFile which returns a module.

http://pastebin.com/t3M9edrT

My issue is that although I have the IR in a string but I am not sure how to add a pass which would use this for the target code generation.

I need some pointers on what to change in the **generateSparcsCode()** function to use the IR I just generated from the **generateCode()** method and stored in the **m_llvmIR** variable.
From the same context, **module** is also a class member and was wondering how I could use that correctly for the target generation code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good resource would be the source code of the **llc** tool (in `tools\llc\llc.cpp`). llc is the LLVM native code generator - it can compile LLVM IR down to target machine code, and you can select a target on the command line (see [this reference](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html) for details).

Just look at the flow of code in the `main` function of **llc**. It reads IR, then sets up the target and finally emits output. You can use the `-filetype` flag to select what **llc** emits (whether it's assembly or a native object with machine code).